# Finding $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\} \left\{\frac{y}{z}\right\}\left\{\frac{z}{x}\right\} dx\space dy\space dz $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\begin{equation}
    \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\} \left\{\frac{y}{z}\right\}\left\{\frac{z}{x}\right\} dx\space dy\space dz \end{equation}$$

I am struggling with the above, I can deal with the case of double integrals but here due to my poor knowledge of triple integrals I am unable to decide what the limits should be in the transformed integral when I apply the substitution $\displaystyle \frac{x}{y}=u\space,\frac{y}{z}=v $ .

The integral turns to $\displaystyle \iiint \left\{u\right\}\left\{v\right\}\left\{\dfrac{1}{uv}\right\}z^2v\space du\space dv\space dz$ , but I have no idea about the limits.

Or even I am doing some mistake in these  steps only.

{.} Denotes Fractional Part

Comment: Can you clarify notation -- does $\{x\}$ mean $x-\lfloor x \rfloor$ ?

Comment: Yes that was fractional part, I'm sorry I forgot to mention it

Comment: Where did you encounter this integral? The reason I ask is that it is listed as one of the 'open problems' in the book *Limits,Series,and Fractional Part Integrals*. There is however, a 'nice' answer for $\int_0^1\int_0^1\left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\}\left\{\frac{y}{x}\right\}\,dx\,dy$.

Comment: Oh I am not aware of this being a open problem. I just tried to evaluate it since we know the double integral case very well. I m stuck with the change of variables stuff a bit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let the considered integral be denoted by $I$. Using the cyclic symmetry of the integrand $f(x,y,z)$ we see that
$$I=\underbrace{3\int_{0<x<y<z<1}\frac{x}{y} \frac{y}{z}\left\{\frac{z}{x}\right\}dxdydz}_{A}+\underbrace{3\int_{0<x<z<y<1}\frac{x}{y} \left\{\frac{y}{z}\right\}\left\{\frac{z}{x}\right\}dxdydz}_{B}
$$

- To calculate $A$ we note that
  $$\eqalign{A&=3\int_{z=0}^1\int_{x=0}^z\frac{(z-x)x}{z}\left\{\frac{z}{x}\right\}dxdz\cr
  &=3\int_{z=0}^1\int_{t=0}^1(z-tz)t\left\{\frac{1}{t}\right\}zdtdz\cr
  &=\int_{z=0}^13z^2dz\int_{t=0}^1(1-t)t\left\{\frac{1}{t}\right\}dt=K_1-K_2
  }$$
  where $K_n=\int_0^1t^n\{1/t\}dt$.
- Similarly, to calculate $B$ we write
  $$\eqalign{B&=3\int_{y=0}^1\int_{z=0}^y\int_{x=0}^z\frac{x}{y} \left\{\frac{y}{z}\right\}\left\{\frac{z}{x}\right\}dxdzdy\cr
  &=3\int_{y=0}^1\int_{z=0}^y\int_{t=0}^1\frac{tz}{y} \left\{\frac{y}{z}\right\}\left\{\frac{1}{t}\right\}zdtdzdy\cr
  &=3\int_{y=0}^1\int_{s=0}^1\int_{t=0}^1ts \left\{\frac{1}{s}\right\}\left\{\frac{1}{t}\right\}sy^2dtdsdy\cr
  &=\int_{y=0}^13y^2\int_{s=0}^1s^2 \left\{\frac{1}{s}\right\}ds\int_{t=0}^1t\left\{\frac{1}{t}\right\}dt=K_1K_2.
  }$$
- It remains to calculate $K_n$ For $n\ge1$. Note that
  $$\eqalign{K_n&=\int_{1}^\infty\frac{\{x\}}{x^{n+2}}dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{n+1}}-\int_1^\infty\frac{\lfloor  x\rfloor}{x^{n+2}}dx\cr
  &=\frac1n-\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\int_k^{k+1}\frac{dx}{x^{n+2}}\cr
  &=\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\left(\frac{1}{k^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^{n+1}}\right)\cr
  &=\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k^{n}}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^{n}}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^{n+1}}\right)\cr
  &=\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+1}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(k+1)^{n+1}}\right)=\frac1n-\frac{\zeta(n+1)}{n+1}.
  }$$
  Thus
  $$K_1=1-\frac{\pi^2}{12},\qquad K_2=\frac12-\frac13 \zeta(3).$$
  And
  $$ I= 1-\frac{\pi^2}{8}+\frac{\pi^2}{36}\zeta(3).$$

Comment: +1 , Please explain me how to get the very first line of the solution, It's excellent but it's true that I cannot understand that splitting very well.

Comment: @AdityaNarayanSharma   Since $f(x,y,z)$ does not change when $x\mapsto y\mapsto z\mapsto x$, you see that the integral on $x< y < z$ is the same as that on the sets $z<x<y$ and $y<z<x$. Similarly, we have three times the integral $x<z<y$.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing again but since in $x<y<z$ we see $0<\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z}<1$ so the fractional part is vanished but in the set $z<x<y$ , $\frac{y}{z}>1$ and in $y<z<x$, $\frac{x}{y}>1$ so the fractional parts doesn't vanish here for both $\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z}$ , Isn't it ? So how the fractional parts vanish here.

Comment: They do not vanish, if $0\le t<1$ then $\{t\}=t$. But  $\{x/y\}\{y/z\} \{z/x\} = \{y/z\}\{z/x\} \{x/y\}$: this is replacing $(x,y,z)$ by $(z,x,y)$.

Comment: No, Integrate first with respect to $y$ from $x$ to $z$ to get $z-x$ then integrate $x$ from $0$ to $z$ and then with respect to $z$ from $0$ to $1$.