# Calculation of $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left\{\frac{y}{x}\right\}\left\{\frac{z}{y}\right\}\left\{ \frac{x}{z}\right\}\,dx\,dy\,dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I 'd like to calculate the integral of the following expression in cube
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left\{\frac{y}{x}\right\}\left\{\frac{z}{y}\right\}\left\{ \frac{x}{z}\right\}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

When I calculate this integral I finally find that this integral has the relation with the infinite sum of $1/n^3$
But I don't know the exact way to calculate this some.
Any one can help me to find the answer?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  I've edited your post to make it more readable, but in the future please see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about using MathJax

Comment: Is $\{t\}$ the fractional part of $t$, or are $\{\_\}$ just parentheses?

Comment: This is my first time for question. So I was wrong for edition. What I wnat to calculate is the product of the fractional part of 3 circulation.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2019967/321264.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\} \left\{\frac{y}{z}\right\}\left\{\frac{z}{x}\right\} dx\space dy\space dz $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019967/finding-int-01-int-01-int-01-left-fracxy-right-left)

Comment: Sorry. I don't know the same question has been asked before. And the answer is the same result that I got. But here I want to know the sum zeta(3). Isn't there a way to calculate the exact sum zeta(3)?